# Logo Centered Responsive Nav Menu

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've found solutions for this problem the old fashioned way but I've got a responsive theme Im tweaking for a personal blog and wanted to figure out if its possible to have a nav menu with a centered image and the menu items float to the right and left of it without the need for using two seperate nav menus.

[image: demo]

This is what I have now, all li items are in one menu.  Im still trying to figure out how I would center the UL in this responsive design and have it scale accordingly. Ive seen examples of how to do it with 2 nav menus but was wondering if this is possible with a responsive design on one menu as I cant find a good example or tutorial.

I do have a temp version of the site here [View It Here](http://walks.hotstickybun.com)

Comment: Can you post a jpg/png of what you want the menu to look like in the smaller viewport?  I can't figure out what end result you are looking for.

Comment: Could I get the recipe for the noodle thingy on your site? No joke – really!

Comment: micadeill, sorry haha Its just an image I grabbed off the web for dummy content

Comment: Lokase, I can design something quickly (just at work) but Im after something similar to what http://www.cacaotour.com/index.php/en/home menu layout is like.

Comment: did u try to just use firebug to inspect that menu and figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just put the centered image IN the middle of the ul? Give it its own li class and just style it accordingly.

Kinda like this http://jsfiddle.net/qWYGR/

the CSS isnt showing up in my jsfiddle. add this

```
​ul {
 display:inline;
 list-style-type:none;        
}
li{
 float:left;   
}
li a {
 float:left;
padding:5px;    
    height:35px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}
.logo img {
 height:100%;
}
```

​

Comment: Im going to try that, Im using Wordpress for this so Ill give it a shot

Comment: if this worked could you accept the answer? it will give you better rep too.